# Is "so to speak" used to express irony here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [some essay](https://monthlyreview.org/2009/05/01/why-socialism/), the author writes that in early civilizations a powerful class controlled the society and exploited people. Then he continues

> But historic tradition is, so to speak, of yesterday; nowhere have we really overcome what Thorstein Veblen called “the predatory phase” of human development.

Does he mean that our society hasn't changed fundamentally in this respect? I'm not sure why he has used "so to speak" here.

Comment: He means that historic tradition is of the past — not that historic tradition is literally of yesterday. *Yesterday* is a figure of speech here.

Comment: It would help if we had more context. Specifically, an interpretation of '**historic tradition**' isn't feasible here as it is. The phrase '**so to speak**' is used as it normally is *to point to metaphoric or expressive language*, viz '**yesterday**' as metaphor for '**the past**'.